# Do related frames and windows share the same JavaScript execution queue?

Tags: javascript

If I have a `frameset` with 2
   `frame`s does each frame have its own
   JavaScript execution queue, making
   the window "multi-threaded"?

What about `iframe`s?

What about child windows?

When I say "execution queue", I'm talking about the same queue used to queue up timers and other events.

The reason I ask is because that I'm wondering if you can run into any multi-threaded-type issues when accessing contexts of scripts in other frames or windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Javascript is strictly single threaded (unless using Web Workers, but that's not relevant here).